# changing the value succ and pred functions returns

Tags: haskell

I would like to define a generic function that gets the next value in a range.  I have the following function definition:

```
nextValInRange :: (Enum a) => a -> a
nextValInRange = succ
```

The problem with the above definition is that for Fractional values, I would like to change the value succ function increments with.  Instead of incrementing by 1.0, I would like succ to increment by 0.2.  For example:

```
(succ 10.0) = 10.2, not 11.0
```

The problem is I still want the nextValInRange function to be for any value that is in Enum type class.

I could write:

```
nextValInRange :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
nextValInRange stepVal rangeVal = rangeVal + stepVal
```

but I do not want to add a Num type class restriction.

Is there some haskell voodoo that I can use to achieve this?

The other solution I can think of is to have 2 separate nextValInRange functions, 1 for Nums and another for normal Enums.

TIA

Comment: I don't think using `Enum` for `Fractional` values is likely to be a good fit for your real task: `succ $ succ $ succ $ succ $ succ 10.0` will not evaluate to `11.0` due to the imprecision of floating point arithmetic. What is your underlying task?

Comment: Consider passing a list of values instead of an initial value.

Comment: The underlying task is that for any value, I need to be able to calculate the next value.  I do not know all the values in the range beforehand.  I need to calculate the next value from the current value.

Comment: No, you've just restated your original question. I ask because I suspect this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am writing my own range library for working with ranges.  As part of this library there is a necessity for me to know for a specific value in the range, what are the next and previous values in the range.  Because this is a generic library, I would like it to work with as many values as possible.  For ranges of say Int and normal enums I can use the Enum class's pred and succ functions, but for Fractals this becomes more hairy.  The reason for all this is that I also have a function which can tell me if 2 ranges are adjacent, with no "spaces" between the 2 ranges.

Comment: So the isRangesAdjacent function uses the succ and pred logic to determine if the 2nd range is directly adjacent to the 1st range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some haskell voodoo that I can use to achieve this?

Essentially, no. You could get it to work with an additional typeclass and some scary LANGUAGE pragmas, but that would probably be more work than just defining instances for your own typeclass in the first place.

I would recommend using `enumFromTo` as Chris suggests, since that is solving basically the same problem that you are solving.

However, you could just turn `nextValInRange` to a function provided by the caller. Suppose it is used in some code like this:

```
makeRange :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]
makeRange lo hi
  | lo < hi = lo : makeRange (nextValInRange lo) hi
  | otherwise = []
```

Simply change the implicit Enum dictionary passing into an explicit function pass

```
makeRange :: (a -> a) -> a -> a -> [a]
makeRange mySucc lo hi
  | lo < hi = lo : makeRange (mySucc lo) hi
  | otherwise = []
```

Then you can pass in the `(+ 0.1)` function for floats, and `succ` for whatever type you feel that is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify how [EnumFromTo](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Prelude.html#v%3aenumFromThenTo) works to fit your needs?  Unless you can use newtype I expect that you need your own polymorphic function or your own type class.

Comment: I don't think I can modify how EnumFromTo works.  I might consider implementing my own type class as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Even if I define my own type class, I will still only get 1 behaviour per type instance.  I will look into newtype and see what the code will look like if I use the newtype mechanism.